# Find the exact line number of error in sql script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert nearly 1000 records for each insert statement in to a table called ZonePlaces. This table is having an Index.

When i try to run the script for insert on this table it throws error

```
Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 56
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ZonePlaces' with unique index 'IX_ZonePlaces'.
```

Line 56 is start of Insert statement.
I know i am inserting something duplicate value but is there a way to find which exact line number has the error?

Hope i am clear.

Comment: Just a suggestion: In SQL Server `INSERT` allows an `OUTPUT` clause. You may want to use it to create a log of your successful inserts.

Comment: The OUTPUT clause helped me. Thank you so much.